# wcf https works on my local pc but not in android

Tags: wcf, ssl, xamarin.forms

I have WCF Service hosted in IIS using https and self sign certificate created from IIS for my local pc

If i enter in my desktop  browser the following link:
https://MyHostName:MyPort/MyService.svc WORKS and is secured.

The same link in different pc in my local LAN gives me warning that this site is not secure and asks me to click and verify that i want to proceed and when i do it i can see the service .. ( which i assume has something to do with my certificate)

**MAIN PROBLEM**

The same link again **FAIL** using android google chrome with out give me a warning . Just fail with the error "This site can't be reached.... ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

Please help.

I am trying to connect to the service from my xamarin Forms android application (https) but before that i try to test the wcf service from my android browser  to verify that the service is available before trying to connect

if this is due to certification how can i configure it correctly to be secure? should i buy one?

i was hoping to test my service before proceeding buying one.

anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using valid certificate fixed the issue.